# Mocking trickier dependencies with Jest [namely nested dependencies based off of index files]

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I've read throughthe other questions regarding mocking with Jest, but I don't really seem to get the hang of it, especially with more complex "replacements".

The thing is also that my dependency isnt just an "import 'X'", but for a more complex nested thingy.

```
const DefaultErrorHandler = require('common').utility.errorHandler.getNoConnectionHandler();
class ErrorHandler extends DefaultErrorHandler {  ...
```

and it's that DefaultErrorHandler thats troubliung me, so I'd like to replace it with my far more manageable MockDefaultErrorHandler.

But how do I do that? No Documentation or other question seems  to fit my case (and/or I'm missing some important point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**its not much different from regular mocking**
In the test code'put: 
const NoConnectionHandler = require('common/lib/utility/error/handler/NoConnectionHandler');

jest.mock('common-bon/lib/utils/error/handler/NoConnectionHandler');

Notice that this path is slightly different than the path i would have intuitively "created" from the require... line.
What saved me was that in the "common" file, the function "getNoConnectionHandler()" itself ends with a require(...)
And the path of that require there was the one I needed.